# Flutter Future and setstate

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to add a Image widget when I get the results of an API call. My code is:

```
class AnimalDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final selection;

  _AnimalDetailsPage createState() => new _AnimalDetailsPage();
  AnimalDetailsPage({Key key, this.selection}) : super(key: key);
}

class _AnimalDetailsPage extends State<AnimalDetailsPage> {

  Future<List> getphotos(horseId) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(
            "http://myhorses.com/api/getHorsePhotos?horse_id=" +
                horseId));
    return JSON.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final menu = new MyMenuBar();

    List<Widget> bodyContent = [menu];
    dynamic body = new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: bodyContent,
    );

    if (widget.selection != null) {
      final horse = widget.selection;
      getphotos(horse['id'].toString()).then((res) {
        setState(() {
          bodyContent.add(new Image.network(res[0]['image']));
        });
      });

    } 

    return Scaffold(
      body: body,
    );
  }
}
```

What I can't manage to understand is that the setState does not updates the view. If I move the setState out of the then statement and hard code the image src, then it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bodyContent` is declared inside `build()`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final menu = new MyMenuBar();

    List<Widget> bodyContent = [menu];
    ...
    bodyContent.add(new Image.network(res[0]['image']));
    ...
```

and `setState()` causes `build` to be executed again, which means the `bodyContent` that holds the image is discarded an a new one created.

Move `List<Widget> bodyContent = [menu];` out of the `build()` method and make it a class-level field and you should get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gunter !